# how to make Toggle button focusable, using tab key

Tags: html, angular, css

I am using this in angular4 environments so afraid of use jquery, Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>
   <div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>
   <div  class="row"> <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label></div>
<div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input type="text"></div>



    .row{
  padding:15px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Below is this URL where this code is working:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eVX3ATeizyuTIkqzmG94?p=preview

I have a few inputs before the toggle, all input is selectable using tab key but toggle button get skipped.

After focus, I need to move this toggle on the arrow press active/deactivate

OR how we can select checkbox using the keyboard.

Comment: Please provide a full html code of your component. It is hard to understand your problem without seeing full picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Although your primary question was answered and now you have borderline a too broad question, here is solution for the updated question:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row"> <input #input1 (keydown)="input2.focus()" type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input #input2 (keydown)="input3.focus()" type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input #input3 (keydown)="input4.focus()" type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" #input4 (keydown)="input5.focus()" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label></div>
<div class="row"> <input #input5 (keydown)="input6.focus()" type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input #input6 (keydown)="input7.focus()" type="text"></div>
<div class="row"> <input #input7  type="text"></div>
```

---

**PRIMARY QUESTION ANSWER:**

Remove this line:

```
.switch input {display:none;}
```

as it's the `input` tag that could get the focus and set an other color when focused to hightlight the focus:

```
input:focus + .slider {
   background-color:red;
   ...
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hphzxd)

Comment: on arrow key it should toggle

Comment: For the arrow key it's out of this question scope, right?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your HTML structure it's hard to tell you how to solve it, but you can add a `tabindex` attribute to your inputs to make the browser know in which order they should be reachable in when tabbing. For example:

```html
<input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggle">
<input tabindex="2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggle">
<input tabindex="3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggle">
<input tabindex="4" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggle">
```

This should force the browser to not skip one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `tabindex="0"` on both: input and span:

`<input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" checked>
 <span class="slider round" tabindex="0"></span>`

It works for me